# Eclipse: How to prevent an entire rebuild of a project after changing classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, buildpath

Is there away to prevent eclipse from rebuilding the entire project every time I change an entry in the class path. Unfortunately, I have to play around with the build path often and rebuilding the projects takes a long time (easily 20-30 mins). Is there away to avoid this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should do the same thing it does when you change your source code: analyze what are the actual changes and perform an incremental build based on those.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way is turn off "Build Automatically" in Main Menu: Project/Build Automatically. This turns off auto-build mode, so you can trigger it manually (from same Project menu)

Comment: that is not sufficient, because it will force a rebuild of the entire project when a I do want to make a build

Comment: How would compiler know what to do if you changing your build path? It has to check/compile every class to make sure your project still compilable. That is exactly what Eclipse does.